# Switch statement in csh

Tags: linux, switch-statement, csh

I am trying to make a switch statement to work in tcsh but I am not sure why it is not working. I am displaying a menu on the screen and if the option is selected it shows the price and then goes back to the top and repeats until the exit option is selected.

```
#!/bin/csh

clear          
echo -n "Petes A Pizza                 "        
echo -n "                 Menu           "      
echo -n "                                     " 
echo -n "                 Make a selection    " 
echo -n "                         "     
echo -n "               A. Speciality Pizza     "     
echo -n "               B. Veggi Lovers Pizza   "     
echo -n "               C. Meat Lovers Pizza    "       
echo -n "               D. Hawaiian Pizza       "       
echo -n "               E. Cheese Pizza         "     
echo -n "               F. Exit                 "     

set a = $<                      

switch ($a)                    

        case [A] :        
 set A = ((7.99 + 0.07))
                echo $A
                sleep 5
                goto top
        case [B] :              #they choose option 2
                set B = ((8.99 * 0.07) + 8.99)
                echo $B
                sleep 5
                goto top
        case [C] :              #they choose option 3
                set C = ((6.99 * 0.07) + 6.99)
                echo $C
                sleep 5
                goto top
        case [D] :              #they choose option 4
                set D = ((8.49 * 0.07) + 8.49)
                echo $D
                sleep 5
                goto top
        case [E] :              #they choose option 5
                set E = ((3.99 * 0.07) + 3.99)
                echo $E
                sleep 5
        case [F] :             
                exit 0          
                breaksw         

        endsw
end
```

Comment: problem is that you are using csh to begin with :) See [this](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) [Wikipeda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell#switch_statement) has a nice example of syntax

Comment: Why are you using `case [A] :` rather than just `case A :`? Why are you using `echo -n`, which prints all the output on one line? You have no label `top`.

Comment: Thanks I have changed it to case A. I am having trouble doing calculations as it ends up printing the number and other information but not the calculation.

Comment: `csh` uses the built-in `@` command to perform arithmetic, but only on integers. The `expr` command also operates only on integers.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few suggestions that should be enough to help you get it working.

Change `#!/bin/csh` to `#!bin/csh -f`. This tells the shell *not* to read your `~/.cshrc` file, which saves time and can avoid confusion. (If you accidentally write code that depends on aliases you've defined in your `.cshrc`, for example, your script won't work for anyone else.)

If you *must* clear the screen, the `clear` command is the way to do it -- but why? If I want to clear my screen before running your script, I'll do it myself, thank you very much. If I have information on my screen that I don't want to lose, I'll be annoyed when your script decides to erase it for me.

Change all the `echo -n`s to just `echo`. The `-n` option tells `echo` to print its output without a trailing newline; your entire menu will be printed on one line.

The square brackets in your case labels are unnecessary. `case A :` means the same thing as `case [A] :`. Note that you're requiring the user to provide input in upper case, which may be inconvenient.

```
set A = ((7.99 + 0.07))
...
set B = ((8.99 * 0.07) + 8.99)
```

These are inconsistent. It looks like you're trying to compute a base price plus 7% sales tax. For case B, a simpler expression for that is `8.99 * 1.07`.

csh doesn't recognize this `(( ... ))` syntax; I wonder where you got the idea that it does. csh can do arithmetic using the `@` command:

```
@ x = 2 + 2
@ x ++
```

but it only operates on integers.  The `bc` command can do floating-point calculations. You could write something like:

```
set B = `echo 'scale=5; 1.07 * 8.99' | bc`
```

Or, more simply:

```
set B = `echo '1.07 * 8.99' | bc -l
```

but `bc -l` may give you more digits than you want.  `man bc` for more information on the `bc` command, its syntax, and how it works. Remember that the values of csh variables are strings, not numbers.

(I'm not sure `bc` is the best tool for this job.)

Finally, csh is not the best language for writing scripts. I've been using it for more years than I care to admit, and I sometimes have to resort to trial and error to find out how a given piece of syntax will behave; the syntax is poorly defined in many cases, and the man page doesn't always clear things up.

Suggested reading: ["Csh Programming Considered Harmful"](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/), by Tom Christiansen.